# Select column in values, in python

Tags: python, sql

I have a code like the following:

```
   sql_command='''SELECT Grade From GRADES where Student_Number='''+str(id) +''' AND Course_ID IN'''+(list)
   grades=execute_sql(sql_command,sql_cursor)
```

where the list is the a list containing elements in the course_id column satisfying a condition (specific course id),

I want to say, select the only grade where the course_id column is the course_id in my list. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) all elements in the list into one string, e.g.:

```
sql_command ='''SELECT Grade From GRADES where Student_Number='''+str(id) 
sql_command+=''' AND Course_ID IN ('''+ ','.join(list) + ''')'''
```

Comment: the list contains tuples, not str.... is it the same thing to do  or ?@EricBouwers

Comment: That was not clear to me from the question. Assuming that one of the tuple values contains the course id you are interested in you can create a new list with only those values using the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876272/select-value-from-list-of-tuples-where-condition)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- Assuming ID is coming from a user's input, this script is going to have being vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465411/python-mysqldb-insert-with-variables-as-parameters) for an example of using parameters, which are safer.
- The solution to your specific question involves imploding your list:

  format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(list))

Source: [imploding a list for use in a python MySQLDB IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589284/imploding-a-list-for-use-in-a-python-mysqldb-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be done using sqlite3

```
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT Grade From GRADES where Student_Number= ? AND Course_ID IN (?)",
    (id, ','.join(map(str, list)))
)
```

Please don't use %s as its not recommended. Check [sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for more.

Comment: the list contains tuple,not str, is it the same thing to write?@Stephan